# Prove that every retraction function is an identifying function.

Tags: general-topology

Hello i have problems with this prove

Let $X$ be a topological space and consider a subset $A \subset X$ with the induced topology of $X$. A continuous function $r: X \longrightarrow{} A$ is called the retraction function if $r (a) = a $ for all $a \in A$.
Prove that every retraction function is an identifying function.

I do not know how to start

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "identifying function"?

Comment: [This recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4159300/4280) implies your question, see why?